# Kivy ScrollView, unable to scroll , scroll bar not shown

Tags: kivy-language

```
ScrollView:
size_hint_x:None
size_hint_y:None
background_color:[.2,.4,.4,1]
pos_hint:{'center_x':.97,'center_y':.55}
size_hint:.45,.5
GridLayout:
    id:selecteditem
    height: self.minimum_height
    bar_width:3
    cols:1
    padding:1
    spacing:3
    size_hint:.45, .5
```

this is the .kv file code.

```
for i in range(100):
btn = Button(text=str(i), size=(250, 30),
             size_hint=(None, None))
self.othroot.ids.selecteditem.add_widget(btn)
```

this is the code that i used as sample to create a 100 list of button.

Thank you in advance if anyone can help me on this.

[This is the image regarding the issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uYYcn.gif)